# How to get the Token of a fanpage on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, token, fan-page

There are many examples on the web about how to get facebook token of a Fanpage in PHP but basically nehum works.

The tutorial is very bad, do not explain the right way or are outdated.

I would like eum definitive answer. How do I get access_token a Facebook page?

What is the correct PHP code for this?

I have tested several and none works.

Thank you.

Comment: tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: The code is this? 
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/PAGE-ID?fields=access_token');
$response = $request->execute();
$result = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
$pageToken = $result['access_token'];
$facebookSession = new FacebookSession($pageToken);

Comment: you really should not post code in comments...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are looking if you're saying, but IMHO the official docs provide all what is necessary:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0

Comment: Thank you for cooperation but the problem is that for beginners in programming as I understand this advanced code is very complicated. I knew this page but do not understand how to do.

Comment: It's not complicated at all. Grab the sample code, change the permissions according to the docs, and call `/me/accounts`. @luschn even gave a link to his tutorial...

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907802/post-to-a-facebook-page-without-manage-pages-permission-using-php/23908207#23908207 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600796/1603357

Comment: I need help, still can not solve the mystery of how to get the token of a page. Can anyone help?